# How do I setup SSL with NGINX using cer and pfx file

Tags: nginx, ssl, rhel8

I have configured the below file based on the knowledge I gathered after going through various forums, however I do not know from where to get the .crt and .key file. All I have is a cer and pfx file. I want to access the website using https.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`*.cer` is your public key for `ssl_certificate` and `*.pfx` is your private + public key, you need private key for `ssl_certificate_key` directive, first you need to convert both of your files to `PEM` format to be able to use with `nginx`.